# Should an exception in injected DLL crash the whole program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, windows-7, code-injection

I'm injecting a custom DLL into an x86 program. It's successfully injected, but when I cause an exception (like accessing a NULL pointer), it's detaching the DLL, without crashing the whole program.
 Is it how it should be? I want to crash the program actually.
 My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing may be the result of Windows 7's [Program Compatibility Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx). I don't think you can turn it off at the module level, if you know the target process, you can [turn off at the process level](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/0fae122e-5ac2-423e-8630-870f00c6806a).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it depends on the program?  I have a DLL shell extension that I use with Windows Explorer (deskband, registered via regsrv32). If it crashes, it takes Explorer down with it.  My DLL is Delphi, btw, but I don't think that matters here.